# Efficient Alternative to Array.prototype.splice() on an unordered array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Question**

`Array.prototype.splice()` modifies an array in place, returning the removed element(s).

Is there a more efficient way to remove an element from an array, without returning that element, that is functionally equivalent? - **Does it affect memory the same way?**

```
var a = [];

a.length = 500;

a.fill(1);

//--------------------
a[250] = a[499];

a.length--;
//--------------------
```

And

```
var a = [];

a.length = 500;

a.fill(1);

//--------------------
a.splice(250, 1);
//--------------------
```

**Will these arrays contain the same elements (order notwithstanding), and occupy the same amount of memory?**

Comment: `a.length--` ?? So strange...

Comment: Efficient though, am I right?

Comment: Did you [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/) it

Comment: Yes actually, http://jsperf.com/html-canvas-performance/12

Comment: but yes, if the order doesn't matter, moving the last item to the position to be discarded will be much faster. And no, they're not equivalent. I'm sure you're aware that the order won't be the same.

Comment: The two are not the same.  a.splice(25, 1) removes the 26th item from the array (0 base).  a.length-- removes the 500th item from the array.  Both approaches are efficient, depends on what your business logic is though.

Comment: @Will and squint, both typographical errors, fixed.

Comment: Did you actually verify the result of your tests? Because your arrays contain nothing...

Comment: Edited the code, maybe that will make more sense now.

Comment: splice will instantiate a new array (of removed elements), changing length is a truncation. I'm not sure why you think they are 'equivalent'.

Comment: @pvg: He's changing the length because he moved the last item to an earlier index.

Comment: @squint splice returns an array, always. that array has to be instantiated and returned. splice always involves an instantiation of a new array.

Comment: What is `a[250] = a[499];` doing in your eyes?

Comment: @AndrueAnderson - Your lengths are still different.  Unless you splice the last item from the array, the splice(index, 1) will never give your the result the same as array.length--.

Comment: @pvg: Yes, you updated your comment to make clear what you meant. It's a good point but I think he's just talking about the effect on the original array.

Comment: @epascarello In my computer it's assigning a value to a variable, the one at index 499, to the one at index 250 to be exact

Comment: How is that equivalent to the slice() line?

Comment: @Will: It does. `.splice()` reindexes the array when you remove members.

Comment: if you'll take notice of the comment delineation, you'll see that I never said or implied that @epascarello

Comment: The code is doing two different things than...It is like comparing a frying pan to a muffin tin. Yep you can both cook muffins in them, but the outcome is totally different. What your test should be is removing an element out of the middle of an array. Not just removing the last element.

Comment: @squint i'm not actually sure what they're talking about! but if you came up with a call to splice and a re-assign/truncate ops that produced the same result, the call to splice will almost certainly be slower, in most cases/handwave hadndwave JIT magic.

Comment: @epascarello ....if you'll take notice of the comment delineation, *I can only hope* you'll see that I'm *asking* a question, about whether *the two lines in the first code section* are functionally equivalent to *the one line in the second code section*

Comment: @squint - If you mean [1, 2, 3, 4].splice(2, 1) will give me [1, 2, 4], then yes.  splice shifts the remaining items because it removes items based on indexes specified.  I by saying reindex, you don't mean reorder the items.

Comment: They are not equivalent. The outcome is not one to one. [1,2,4,5] !== [1,2,5,4], now if you were inserting a value with splice, that would be different...

Comment: @AndrueAnderson: They're definitely not equivalent since `.splice()` will maintain the original order after the removal by reindexing the array. But if order doesn't matter, the first is very effective.

Comment: @Will: I just meant that the resulting `.length` will be the same in both cases.

Comment: One more function of splice which the question didn't ask is the ability to insert one or more items into the array.

Comment: One more thing, var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].splice(2, 2) will return a new array to x with the values of [ 3, 4 ].  In addition to remove items from the original array, it also returns the items being removed.  Although I haven't had the need to get the removed items.

Comment: @Will It is nice when you are doing a processing recursion. Remove first X elements, send to Y Process, next loop repeat with the updated array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're nowhere near equivalent; even in that sparse array, thinking about it one step further...

```
const arr1 = Array(500).fill();
arr1[arr1.length - 1] = "Bob";

arr1; // 499x undefined, 1x Bob
arr1[250] = arr[499];
arr1.length -= 1;
arr1; // 250x undefined, 1x Bob 248x undefined


// compare the above with
const arr2 = Array(500).fill();
arr2[arr2.length - 1] = "Bob";
arr2.splice(250, 1);
arr2; // 498x undefined 1x Bob


// compare that with
const arr3 = Array(500).fill();
arr3[arr3.length - 1] = "Bob";
const arr4 = arr3.slice(0, 250).concat(arr3.slice(251));
arr3; // 499x undefined 1x Bob
arr4; // 498x undefined 1x Bob


// if you wanted to hand-wind a "splice" which did actually work the way you thought it did,
// you might try soemething like

function splice (arr, start, offset) {
  let i = 0;
  while (start + i + offset < arr.length) {
    arr[start + i] = arr[start + i + offset];
    i += 1;
  }
  arr -= offset;
}
```

I may have an off-by-one error in that last function; I'm trying to enter vacation-mode.

I haven't had one of those for a few years, at this point.

Comment: For the record, I'm asking a question. I haven't indicated my thoughts on the matter, whatever you're referring to is conjecture.

Comment: Take at look at the fill function..(it fills the array with 1s, not undefined) @Norguard

Comment: @AndrueAnderson What do you mean, conjecture? How is comparing any of those 4 examples to one another conjecture about their functionality?

Comment: "which did actually work the way you thought it did" @Norguard - conjecture about the nature of my thoughts

Comment: @AndrueAnderson "It fills the arrays with 1"...  ...and? Regardless of the fact that JS will treat scalars based on value, rather than referential equality, do you mean to ask that you are ***only ever going to use this information expressly for an array of exactly 500 `1`s***? If so, is this also a compiler-optimization question, regarding hot-paths in particular engines?  The point is that as soon as it's not all 1s, your supposition is broken. You don't even have to reassign the indices in the first place, if it's just 1s, so what are you accomplishing by doing so?

Comment: Again, what was my supposition? @Norguard?

Comment: @AndrueAnderson "Is there a more efficient way to remove an element from an array, without returning that element, that is functionally equivalent? - Does it affect memory the same way?" See the function written.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson Meanwhile, I've provided not only the answer to that question, but also examples of all other traditional means of slicing up arrays, including views into both the referential equality of the indices, and the referential equality of the arrays, themselves.

Comment: You're doing a lot of talking, but not making much sense. @Norguard I still can't get you to tell me what you think I'm supposing that doesn't hold for objects?

Comment: @AndrueAnderson `a[250] = a[499];`  Makes absolutely no sense. Accomplishes nothing. Changes the index of a reference (as evidenced by my examples, which extend much further when mapping over real objects, not scalars). What part of what I've written makes no sense? Because as far as I'm aware, I've provided not only the answers, but the practical examples to your questions, extrapolated into a practical application, rather than a realm where all arrays are filled with `1`.

Comment: Your 'answer' is nothing more than a sad attempt at rep-farming and sharing personal facts that no one cares about. Try out what you've just posted as an 'example' (i.e. a[250] = a[499]) with objects. I feel like you're *using* a browser, how can you not determine the falsehood of that on your own?

Comment: "Accomplishes nothing" - nothing except reducing the size of an array by ridding itself of an arbitrary index (250) through reassignment much faster than a call to Array.prototype.splice()

Comment: @AndrueAnderson Personal facts? `const arr = Array(500).fill().map( (_, i) => ({ index: i }) ); arr[250] = arr[499];` Now tell me, exactly, how your first two "equivalent" operations are equivalent. Your indices are completely messed. Also, how are you handling the offset? Also, how are you handling the insert?

Comment: Refer to my first comment @Norguard with respect to "how my first two 'equivalent' operations are equivalent"

Comment: @AndrueAnderson you asked, specifically...  ...like...  ...specifically, in your question text, whether they are equivalent operations.

Comment: ...which would imply that I know there are alternative options to "Yes, they are" @Norguard - the exact opposite of referring to them as being equivalent

Comment: @AndrueAnderson ...alternative? Alternative suggests that "Yes they are" is an option. It is not. At all. It will not pass any assertion library's check for equivalence.

Comment: I came into the discussion without bias, therefore both "Yes" and "No" were options....something you could try to do - no one cares what you have to say when it's backed solely by personal experience. We all have our own personal experience, and it generally doesn't apply well to all @Norguard

Comment: @AndrueAnderson If you have a proposition; a dispute; a fallacy in my logic, feel free to show me where it is. I will happily concede that I'm wrong (in fact, I already did, in the comments which I wrote, above the splice which I wrote in a minute or two, without much thought).  My bias is towards giving practical answers, when possible. In an array full of one single value, and only ever one single value (or cases in which you ensure that the index you are replacing is already a scalar exactly equal to the last index), you're set... of course, you don't have to swap, then.

Comment: The fallacy in your logic is that someone else's use case is equivalent to yours. What's practical to you may not be practical in all cases, if you're referring to something being backed by practice it is the opposite of having been general (the act of the practice sets a constant use case, a constant user) @Norguard

Comment: @AndrueAnderson I'm not arguing experiences; I'm arguing functional programming. The transform is not *remotely* the same. I do not have equivalent sets of data, at all. Thus, ***any/every person*** who attempts to engage in that style of programming, expecting specific results, will fail to see them. Any reasonable assertion library set to do a test of all input is going to explode when comparing the output of the two formats. That's not "me", nor "my experience". That's referential equality, which is provable with the very browser you asked me to use, plus anything reachable via NPM.

Comment: 1. read the question, 2. argue a point that applies to the same context

Comment: @AndrueAnderson again, if your personal experience is such that order in JavaScript arrays is **never** significant, then you have my apologies, and my humble retraction of all of the above; we work in two exceedingly different worlds.

Comment: Indeed we do. I believe I'm using it much more like a *list* than an array

Comment: @AndrueAnderson You might consider `Set`, when duplicates are unnecessary (`.add`, `.delete` and `.has` are much handier than the alternatives), and byte-arrays, when you're storing (or referencing into) blobs of data.

Comment: @Norguard, I don't know you bother, OP is arrogant and out of reality.

Comment: @ShanShan that's not a fair statement. Context is everything.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson also, I believe your question of whether they occupy the exact same amount of memory comes down to the particular browser you care to inquire about. Your manual optimization may actually prevent memory-recovery in various engines (though, that memory may not be recovered via `splice`, either, again, depending). It comes down to what's being used as the backing store, in the engine. In Chrome (at least around 2012) it optimized for int-storage, for small arrays, and then devolved into dictionaries if the size grew, or if it started storing non-ints.

Comment: @Norguard You clearly answered the question and he started attacking you and wasting your time. I guess you're much more patient than I am.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson Most other browsers of the time had far less sophisticated VMs (including the tired old ActiveX beasts which still have a global foothold). There's no real method of accurately peering into all implementations (again, practicality demands knowing what you as an individual both need to, and are likely to, support, throughout your product's lifetime), in order to see which ones will optimize for memory, in which cases (as that's an entirely non-JS, browser-specific thing).

Comment: @ShanShan We're all in need of more patience and more context. I'm certainly not as good at it as I should be, when I'm not on the clock.